# MicroServicio STS con MongoDB: return status error 404

Tags: mongodb, spring, spring-boot, postman, microservices

Hola buenos días/tardes/noches, soy nuevo trabajando con MicroServicios y estoy bloqueado. No se que puedo estar haciendo mal y no encuentro solución por internet.

Lanzando la siguiente petición en Postman recibo el error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Supongo que el MicroServicio no está disponible y no sé a qué se puede deber. El MicroServicio está corriendo (sin errores) en Spring Boot en el puerto 11704, (application.properties)

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri= mongodb://localhost/triplandb 
# HTTP Server
server.port = 11704
```

Y el controlador tiene el siguiente código:

```
@RestController
public class RegistroControlador {

@Autowired
RegistroRepositorio registroRepositorio;

@RequestMapping(value = "/usuario", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<?> nuevoUsuario(@RequestBody Usuario usuario) {
    
    System.out.println("Accede a la función del microservicio: nuevoUsuario()");

    try {
        Usuario entity = registroRepositorio.save(usuario);
        
        return new ResponseEntity<>(entity, HttpStatus.OK);

    } catch (Exception ex) {

        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}                                                                       }
```

¿Podrían ayudarme a encontrar mi error? Sospecho que puede ser un error con la configuración o algo parecido... Muchas gracias de antemano y un saludo

Comment: Por favor, el código debe ir en formato de texto y [no en imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2990/un-fragmento-de-código-vale-más-que-mil-imágenes-cómo-sensibilizar-a-los-usu/3976#3976). Saludos

Comment: Ya lo cambio, gracias

Comment: Ya veo. El error está en la forma en la que envías la data desde Postman. Esto: `{Usuario: { ... } }`. Estás enviando un objeto que tiene un atributo o propiedad `Usuario` la cual contiene los datos del usuario. Pero tu controlador no espera esa estructura. Espera simplemente los datos del usuario como atributos del objeto raíz. Prueba de enviar la data así: `{ nombre: <valor>, correo: <valor>, ... }` desde Postman y comenta el resultado. Saludos

Comment: Hola Mauricio gracias por tu respuesta. Hice el cambio pero aún así, sigue dando error 404.

Comment: Si realizaste el cambio colócalo en la pregunta para verificar que estas enviando ahora, además si puede colocar el log de inicio de la aplicación.

Answer (score 0):

Este fallo es muy común para los que van empezando con la arquitectura de spring boot, revisa lo siguiente:

1. Revisa en el archivo application.properties por si hay algún
   server.contextPath=
2. De no haber algún path revisar la clase de arranque, comunmente
   tiene una estructura como la siguiente.

   ```
    public class AppApplication  implements WebMvcConfigurer {    
         public static void main(String[] args) {
           System.setProperty("server.servlet.context-path", "/app");
          SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        }
      }
   ```
3. Puede que también se tenga en variables de entorno.
   Windows:  Haga clic con el botón derecho en el icono de Computadora y luego vaya a
   Propiedades -> Configuración avanzada del sistema -> Variables de entorno y
   busque SERVER_CONTEXT_PATH.
4. Si el path del contexto no aparece, copia el nombre de tu proyecto,
   por ejemplo.

   El proyecto se llama **EjemploApi**, ese sería tu context path

   ```
      http://localhost:11704/EjemploApi/usuarios
   ```